# Member 'success' in 'Result<AnyObject, NSError>' produces result of type 'Result<Value, Error>', but context expects 'Result<AnyObject, NSError>'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, alamofire

Recently i just converted swift 2.3 project to 3.2 , alamofire also got converted, and i received many issues solved most of them, now i am stuck with the given two issue

the issue was faced in ResponseSerialization.swift file in alamofire

```
/**
    Creates a response serializer that returns a JSON object constructed from the response data using 
    `NSJSONSerialization` with the specified reading options.

    - parameter options: The JSON serialization reading options. `.AllowFragments` by default.

    - returns: A JSON object response serializer.
*/
public static func JSONResponseSerializer(
    options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments)
    -> ResponseSerializer<AnyObject, NSError>
{
    return ResponseSerializer { _, response, data, error in
        guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

        if let response = response, response.statusCode == 204 { return .success(NSNull()) }

        guard let validData = data, validData.count > 0 else {
            let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length."
            let error = Error.error(code: .jsonSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            return .failure(error)
        }

        do {
            let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: validData, options: options)
            return .success(JSON) //getting error over here
        } catch {
            return .failure(error as NSError)
        }
    }
}
```

getting the error as Member 'success' in 'Result' produces result of type 'Result', but context expects 'Result'
same issue facing for the following code in the same file

```
/**
    Creates a response serializer that returns an object constructed from the response data using 
    `NSPropertyListSerialization` with the specified reading options.

    - parameter options: The property list reading options. `NSPropertyListReadOptions()` by default.

    - returns: A property list object response serializer.
*/
public static func propertyListResponseSerializer(
    options: PropertyListSerialization.ReadOptions = PropertyListSerialization.ReadOptions())
    -> ResponseSerializer<AnyObject, NSError>
{
    return ResponseSerializer { _, response, data, error in
        guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

        if let response = response, response.statusCode == 204 { return .success(NSNull()) }

        guard let validData = data, validData.count > 0 else {
            let failureReason = "Property list could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length."
            let error = Error.error(code: .propertyListSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            return .failure(error)
        }

        do {
            let plist = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: validData, options: options, format: nil)
            return .success(plist)
        } catch {
            return .failure(error as NSError)
        }
    }
}
```

searched everywhere for the solution, but didn't find, please help me in this,

thanks in advance

Comment: i did not convert it, it was automatically done by xcode

Comment: Remove it then and add the swift 3.2 compatible version of Alamofire.

Comment: I was getting such error coz I was passing Optional in `.success()`

Answer (score 0):

Swift-5 Simple replace this code

```
public static func propertyListResponseSerializer(
    options: PropertyListSerialization.ReadOptions = [])
    -> DownloadResponseSerializer<Any>
{
    return DownloadResponseSerializer { _, response, fileURL, error in
        guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

        guard let fileURL = fileURL else {
            return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .inputFileNil))
        }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            return Request.serializeResponsePropertyList(options: options, response: response, data: data, error: error)
        } catch {
            return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .inputFileReadFailed(at: fileURL)))
        }
    }
}
```